# Raymarching (fixed steps, increasing step size)

Tags: algorithms

I have two points, "near" and "far", on a line (e.g. near = 0.5 and far = 1000.0). I wish to step along the line from near to far in a certain number of steps (e.g. 256).

I would like the step size to increase linearly with distance from near, something like the following algorithm:

```
const float min_step = 0.01;

float t = near;
float dt = min_step;

const int imax = 256;

for (int i = 0; i != imax; ++i)
{
    t += dt;

    if (t > far)
        break;

    // use t...

    dt = min_step * t;
}
```

However, I do not know what to set the minimum step size to, in order to reach exactly the right number of steps at the far point. This leads to a lot of faffing to find the right value for a given number of steps.

Is there an equation that would allow me to simply calculate the distance t for a given step without having to fiddle with values? I don't mind if the min step size changes, as long as it's easily calculable.

(I'm not really sure what to tag this as, sorry). I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$s_n = d_{n-1} \times s_1$$

And

$$d_n = d_{n-1}+s_n $$

Where $d_n$ is the distance traveled after the $n$ first steps and $s_n$ is the n-th step size

So you have that

$$s_2 = s_1^2$$
$$d_2 = s_1 + s_1^2 = s_1( 1+s_1)$$

$$s_3 = s_1^2 + s_1^3$$
$$d_3 = s_1 + s_1^2 + ( s_1^2 + s_1^3 ) = s_1 ( 1+2s_1 +s_1^2) = s_1 (1+s_1)^2$$

Start to see a pattern?

Now let's take $n$ such that $d_n = s_1 (1+s_1)^{n-1}$

You have

$$s_{n+1} = s_1^2(1+s_1)^{n-1}$$

$$d_{n+1} = s_1 (1+s_1)^{n-1} + s_1^2(1+s_1)^{n-1} = s_1(1+s_1)(1+s_1)^{n-1} = s_1(1+s_1)^n$$

So by reccurence, we have for all $n$

$d_n = s_1 (1+s_1)^{n-1}$

Now you want to find $x$ such that

$far-near = x (1+x)^{255}$

Unfortunatly, this is not solvable by algebrical means, and you'll need to solve this equation numerically (for exemple with the Newton raphson method)